# Pasar datos de la vista al controlador

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Tengo una etiqueta "a" en otra vista y otro controlador que no es del controlador cliente

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
            <a asp-action="Cliente" asp-controller="Cliente" class="">@item.Razonsocial</a>
        </div>
```

he pensado en los Helpers de ASP para pasarle algo como parametro.

como hago para pasarle como parametro el @item.nombre desde la vista X al controlador de cliente?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Cliente(string nit)
    {
        if(nit == null)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Debe ingresar Nit o Nombre del cliente";
            return View("Index");
        }

        var a = await _clienteService.GetClientesAsync(nit);

        if (!a.Any())
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "El cliente no existe o no pertenece a su zona de distribución";
            return View("Index");
        }

        return View("Index", a);
    }
```

Este es el controlador que lo recibe; si recibe una lista, en la vista me muestra unos datos, si recibe un solo dato, me muestra los datos del cliente, eso es lo que quiero al pasarle el nombre

Comment: Agrega el código que mencionas porque sólo veo un anchor :)

Comment: <a asp-action="BuscarCliente" asp-controller="Cliente">@item.nombre</a>

Comment: sigo viendo un anchor...

Comment: ya lo puedes ver?

Comment: no me estoy dejando entender, creo que la respuesta te puede ser de utilidad

Comment: la verdad no, que fragmento de codigo te dejo ver, porque lo que necesito es pasarle ese valor de item a otro controlador

Comment: revisa la respuesta, me late que es lo que buscas :D

Comment: Seria bueno conocer como recibe el controlador el parametro "nombre" o como lo quieres recibir? es decir su podemos pasarle por GET (o sea por la  URL / Querystring) o debe enviarse por POST y alli si es de otra forma.

Comment: @JoseA.Fernandez, todos los anchor generan un GET al servidor, no hay chance de que un anchor genere un POST by default, a menos que se le implemente un preventDefault y un AJAX de por medio.

Comment: Ahí esta el controlador, si recibe una lista, en la vista me muestra unos datos, si recibe un solo dato, me muestra los datos del cliente, eso es lo que quiero al pasarle el nombre

Comment: if(nit == null) -> if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(nit))

Comment: @fredyfx Si todos los anchor lo hacen! pero hay veces que hay que hacer POST y bueno alli el anchor deberia enviar un formulario al hacer click (incluso crear mediante js un form on-the-fly")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dejo otro ejemplo que te puede servir de ayuda

```
 public class JediController : Controller
{
    [Route("Jedi/{name}")]
    public IActionResult Details(string name)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The name is required"); 
        }

        var jedi = new Jedi()
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = name
        };
        return View(jedi);
    }
}
```

Y en la vista los anchor con tagHelper de route

```
@model Starwars.App.Web.Entities.Jedi
@{
 ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
 Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

Jedi: <strong>@Model.Name</strong>


  <ul>
      <li>
          <a asp-controller="Jedi"
             asp-action="Details"
             asp-route-name="@Model.Name">
              @Model.Name
          </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
 Another examples:
  <ul>
      <li>
          <a asp-controller="Jedi"
             asp-action="Details"
             asp-route-name="Yoda">
              Yoda
          </a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a asp-controller="Jedi"
             asp-action="Details"
             asp-route-name="Luke Skywalker">
              Luke Skywalker
          </a>
      </li>
  </ul>
```

Enlaces que te pueden ayudar

- Controller ASP.NET Core With route attribute and anchor with TagHelper Route #aspnetcore asp-rute https://gist.github.com/fernandezja/070599445f1ece2b2d2a93aa0968bf90
- [@docsmsft > Anchor Tag Helper](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper)
- [@docsmsft > Introduction to using tag helpers in forms in ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms)

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a lo que veo, esto te puede ser de utilidad

```
<a asp-controller="Cliente" 
   asp-action="Detalle" 
   asp-route-id="@item.nombre ">
@item.Razonsocial</a>
```

Esto genera:

```
<a href="/Cliente/Detalle/AlgunNombreAqui">Aqui va alguna razon social</a>
```

Comment: Para que funcione este anchor con TagHelper deberias decorar tu metodo/actionresult con 
[Route("NombreController/Cliente/{nit}")] y que el nombre del parametro es nit y no id. Ademas hay que cambiar en  asp-route-nit="@Model.nombre" (no se si es el modelo y otro objeto dentro de la vista)

Comment: es lo más probable, como dije en la respuesta, de acuerdo a lo que veo. No hay más detalles en la pregunta y bueno ahí va una respuesta :D

Comment: Un ejemplo lo dejo por aqui con un controller y la vista
https://gist.github.com/fernandezja/070599445f1ece2b2d2a93aa0968bf90 ... a ver si puedo hacer con un post desde el anchor asi ya queda ;)

Comment: creo que caería mejor como respuesta que como comentario hermano :D

Answer (score 0):

```
[Route("Cliente/{nit}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Cliente(string nit)
    {
        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(nit))
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Debe ingresar Nit o Nombre del cliente";
            return View("Index");
        }

        var a = await _clienteService.GetClientesAsync(nit);

        if (!a.Any())
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "El cliente no existe o no pertenece a su zona de distribución";
            return View("Index");
        }
        return View("Index", a);
    }
```

Así me funcionó, muchas gracias a todos por los aportes.